# How to export to local file with scrapy python on windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Does anybody know how can I export and store a file(could be json) to/in local file system on Windows with python scrapy?
In this guide it says storage in local file just is possible for unix systems.
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html 
How can I store crawled data files in local file system on windows working with scrapy python?

Comment: The guide says you can omit the scheme  `file:` on UNIX only, nothing else.

Comment: you have option `-o filename.json` to save data in file. Doc: [Storing the scraped data](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#storing-the-scraped-data)

Comment: It does not work, because you did not prefix it with `file:`.

Comment: @KlausD.Thanks for the advice. It worked :)